# Texture painting, zoom pan causes texture to get an offset

Tags: 3d-view, texture-painting

Hi I have a problem when texture painting on a huge plane.

Whenever I zoom or pan my view (even just pan without zooming) and paint on a location I painted before, the texture gets an offset and of course does not fit anymore to the rest I painted.

Answer (score 5):

You can use stencil for the brush mapping. This gives you a semi-transparent overlay of the texture that you can position before painting.

[image]

You can use <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to move the texture <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to rotate it and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to scale it